# Sending messages through LoRaWAN using STM32

Tags: stm32, lora, lorawan, stm32ldiscovery

How do I send the messages through LoRaWAN?

```
static void PrepareTxFrame( uint8_t port )
{
switch( port ) {
    case 10: {
        int pos = 0;

        pc.printf("Prepare message\n");
#if 0
        uint32_t tempValue = ( uint32_t )( LightValue * 1000000.0 );
        AppData[0] = LightMode;
        AppData[1] = ( ( tempValue & 0xFF000000 ) >> 24 ) & 0xFF;
        AppData[2] = ( ( tempValue & 0x00FF0000 ) >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
        AppData[3] = ( ( tempValue & 0x0000FF00 ) >> 8 ) & 0xFF;
        AppData[4] = ( tempValue & 0x000000FF );
#else
        AppData[pos] = count;

        pc.printf("\n\r");
        pc.printf("The value of the counter is : %d", count);
        count++;
        pc.printf("\n\r");

        time_t seconds = time(NULL);
        printf("The time is %s", ctime(&seconds));
        AppData[++pos] = seconds;


        pc.printf("%d \n %d", AppData[0], AppData[1]);
        pc.printf("\n\r");
#endif
        pc.printf("Message Ready\n");
    }
    break;
    case 15: {
        int pos = 0;
        AppData[pos++] = AppLedStateOn;
#if 0

        if( IsTxConfirmed == true )
        {
            AppData[pos++] = LoRaMacDownlinkStatus.DownlinkCounter >> 8;
            AppData[pos++] = LoRaMacDownlinkStatus.DownlinkCounter;
            AppData[pos++] = LoRaMacDownlinkStatus.Rssi >> 8;
            AppData[pos++] = LoRaMacDownlinkStatus.Rssi;
            AppData[pos++] = LoRaMacDownlinkStatus.Snr;
        }
#endif
        AppDataSize = pos;
    }
    break;
    case 224:
        if( ComplianceTest.LinkCheck == true ) {
            ComplianceTest.LinkCheck = false;
            AppDataSize = 3;
            AppData[0] = 5;
            AppData[1] = ComplianceTest.DemodMargin;
            AppData[2] = ComplianceTest.NbGateways;
            ComplianceTest.State = 1;
        } else {
            switch( ComplianceTest.State ) {
                case 4:
                    ComplianceTest.State = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    AppDataSize = 2;
                    AppData[0] = ComplianceTest.DownLinkCounter >> 8;
                    AppData[1] = ComplianceTest.DownLinkCounter;
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
 }

/*!
 * \brief
 *
  * Prepares the pay-load of the frame
  *
 * \retval  [0: frame could be send, 1: error]
 */
static bool SendFrame( void )
{
 McpsReq_t mcpsReq;
 LoRaMacTxInfo_t txInfo;

if( LoRaMacQueryTxPossible( AppDataSize, &txInfo ) != LORAMAC_STATUS_OK ) 
      {
    // Send empty frame in order to flush MAC commands
    mcpsReq.Type = MCPS_UNCONFIRMED;
    mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.fBuffer = NULL;
    mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.fBufferSize = 0;
    mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.Datarate = LORAWAN_DEFAULT_DATARATE;

    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.Acked = false;
    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.Port = 0;
    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.Buffer = NULL;
    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.BufferSize = 0;
    SerialDisplayUpdateFrameType( false );
} else {
    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.Acked = false;
    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.Port = AppPort;
    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.Buffer = AppData;
    LoRaMacUplinkStatus.BufferSize = AppDataSize;
    SerialDisplayUpdateFrameType( IsTxConfirmed );

    if( IsTxConfirmed == false ) {
        mcpsReq.Type = MCPS_UNCONFIRMED;
        mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.fPort = AppPort;
        mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.fBuffer = AppData;
        mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.fBufferSize = AppDataSize;
        mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.Datarate = LORAWAN_DEFAULT_DATARATE;
    } else {
        mcpsReq.Type = MCPS_CONFIRMED;
        mcpsReq.Req.Confirmed.fPort = AppPort;
        mcpsReq.Req.Confirmed.fBuffer = AppData;
        mcpsReq.Req.Confirmed.fBufferSize = AppDataSize;
        mcpsReq.Req.Confirmed.NbTrials = 8;
        mcpsReq.Req.Confirmed.Datarate = LORAWAN_DEFAULT_DATARATE;
    }
}

if( LoRaMacMcpsRequest( &mcpsReq ) == LORAMAC_STATUS_OK ) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Will the counter data and the time be sent? Also is the data in AppData the ones to be transmitted? I want the count and the timestamp to be sent every time the LoRa device transmits.

Comment: Do you want to know whether your code is going to work ? Or knowing what data will be sent *physically*?

Comment: I want to know what data will be sent physically. Is it the data in AppData? Because the data I want to send is _count_ and _seconds_ . And I stored them in AppData. But, I'm not sure if that is the data that will be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload to send (`AppData`) is given to the LoRaMAC layer through the MCPS (MAC Common Part Sublayer) request, e.g. for an unconfirmed frame:

```
mcpsReq.Req.Unconfirmed.fBuffer = AppData;
```

So *physically* (i.e. by RF), `AppData` is sent but it's encrypted and encapsulated before.

`PrepareFrame()` function builds the frame to send according to the `PHYPayload` scheme (See the "MAC Message Formats" part in the LoRaWAN™ Specification 1.0.2 document), following these fields:

- `MHDR` (1 byte) Mac header
- `DevAddr` (4 bytes) Address of the end-device
- `FCtrl` (1 byte) Frame control
- `FCnt` (2 bytes) Frame counter
- `FOpts` (0 - 15 bytes) Frame options
- `FPort` (0 - 1 byte) Port field
- `FRMPayload` (0 - N bytes) MAC Frame Payload Encryption, your **`AppData`** encrypted
- `MIC` (4 bytes) Message Integrity Code

`FRMPayload` is encrypted according to FPort. The encryption algorithm is based on AES 128.
If `FPort` = [1..255], the `AppSKey` key will be used to encrypt your payload.
Else (`FPort` = 0), it's encrypted by using the `NwkSKey` key.
*See the `LoRaMacPayloadEncrypt()` function for more details.*

`PHYPayload` will be encapsulated by the `Radio PHY Layer` and sent through RF.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I decrypt the data I am receiving?

Comment: Where do you read your data that you're receiving? For example you can use this [packet decoder](https://lorawan-packet-decoder-0ta6puiniaut.runkit.sh/) with the data read from your gateway's logs.

Comment: I'm reading the data from a gateway hosted by TATA. Thank you for the link.